# why my hard drive is readonly? and how to fix it

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, formatting, read-only

I formatted my laptop

and now i am getting that my hard drive (D:) is read-only and I cannot partition it or copy any files on it.

[image]

I tried to add "Everyone" and gave that user full access but got this error message

how can i fix that?

[image]

Comment: How old is that drive? It likely failed. That not being the case how exactly have you formatted it?

Answer (score 2):

Modern SSD drives try to fail "gracefully" by becoming read-only when a fatal issue is detected. SSD's have a finite number of write cycles, so an attempt to completely overwrite it could destroy it. If that is the cause of the issue, that drive is not heavy enough to even serve as a serve as a [boat anchor](https://www.dictionary.net/boat%20anchor).

However, you **can** try a third-party such as free [DiskGenius](https://www.diskgenius.com/) or an [alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/diskgenius/). Note that most such tools require **two** steps for each operation, i.e., *Apply* or *Confirm*, to help avoid accidental errors.

- Remove all partitions from D:, apply.
- Create a single partition, apply.
- Format that partition, likely NTFS, apply.

Windows (or Linux) should automatically recognize the drive and mount it, if the operations worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

1- Open Command Prompt as Administrator

2- Type "DiskPart"

3- Type "select disk 0"

4- Type "attributes disk"

5- Type "attributes disk clear readonly"